# ¿Cómo desactivar una propiedad para actualizar pero no para crear con OpenXava?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, openxava

Tengo una propiedad llamada fecha donde el usuario debería poder introducir valores al crear una nueva entidad:

[image: Fecha editable al crear]

Sin embargo, al editar una entidad existente la propiedad fecha no debería ser editable, de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay una forma sencilla de declarar una propiedad editable sólo al crear en una entidad OpenXava?

Answer (score 0):

Sí, simplemente anota tu propiedad con @ReadOnly(onCreate=false):

```
@ReadOnly(onCreate=false)
LocalDate fecha;
```

No necesitas nada más.